# I'm making a drawing tool. How come when I'm drawing it draws OK, but after I draw allot, let go, and start drawing again, it's REALLY slow

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm using HTML5 and JS to create my it. When I start drawing it makes drawings without much lag. After I draw just a little bit, let go of the mouse, and start again it takes a few seconds to start drawing.
**Edit:** Also, after drawing for a while, I get very pointy shapes. Any ideas why?

**Edit:**

I added a code snippet as per the rules and a comment.

```js
class Drawing {
 // So after many get-back-togethers I've finally broke up with JavaScript's arguments keyword which just does not compare to an array.
 // Now you have to provide an Array as args even if you only have one arg.
 // Every Drawing object needs to store the event that created it. This is needed for ctrl-z to be able to revert to the last pointerdown
 constructor(args, ev) {
  for (var arg of args) {
   // Every arg used when creating a Drawing must have a function to be called when that drawing is drawn. Otherwise, there won't be anything to do.
   if (!(arg.func))
    throw Error("A function must be provided!");
   // Make sure the function exists within ctx.
   if (!CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.hasOwnProperty(arg["func"]))
    throw Error(`${arg['func']} is not a property of the CanvasRenderingContext2D prototype!`);
  }
  // When a Drawing instance is drawn, it will call all it's functions in this.functions with their appropriate args.
  this.functions = args;
  this.ev = ev;
 }
}
const CSS_COLORS = //["AliceBlue","AntiqueWhite","Aqua","Aquamarine","Azure","Beige","Bisque","Black","BlanchedAlmond","Blue","BlueViolet","Brown","BurlyWood","CadetBlue","Chartreuse","Chocolate","Coral","CornflowerBlue","Cornsilk","Crimson","Cyan","DarkBlue","DarkCyan","DarkGoldenRod","DarkGray","DarkGrey","DarkGreen","DarkKhaki","DarkMagenta","DarkOliveGreen","Darkorange","DarkOrchid","DarkRed","DarkSalmon","DarkSeaGreen","DarkSlateBlue","DarkSlateGray","DarkSlateGrey","DarkTurquoise","DarkViolet","DeepPink","DeepSkyBlue","DimGray","DimGrey","DodgerBlue","FireBrick","FloralWhite","ForestGreen","Fuchsia","Gainsboro","GhostWhite","Gold","GoldenRod","Gray","Grey","Green","GreenYellow","HoneyDew","HotPink","IndianRed","Indigo","Ivory","Khaki","Lavender","LavenderBlush","LawnGreen","LemonChiffon","LightBlue","LightCoral","LightCyan","LightGoldenRodYellow","LightGray","LightGrey","LightGreen","LightPink","LightSalmon","LightSeaGreen","LightSkyBlue","LightSlateGray","LightSlateGrey","LightSteelBlue","LightYellow","Lime","LimeGreen","Linen","Magenta","Maroon","MediumAquaMarine","MediumBlue","MediumOrchid","MediumPurple","MediumSeaGreen","MediumSlateBlue","MediumSpringGreen","MediumTurquoise","MediumVioletRed","MidnightBlue","MintCream","MistyRose","Moccasin","NavajoWhite","Navy","OldLace","Olive","OliveDrab","Orange","OrangeRed","Orchid","PaleGoldenRod","PaleGreen","PaleTurquoise","PaleVioletRed","PapayaWhip","PeachPuff","Peru","Pink","Plum","PowderBlue","Purple","Red","RosyBrown","RoyalBlue","SaddleBrown","Salmon","SandyBrown","SeaGreen","SeaShell","Sienna","Silver","SkyBlue","SlateBlue","SlateGray","SlateGrey","Snow","SpringGreen","SteelBlue","Tan","Teal","Thistle","Tomato","Turquoise","Violet","Wheat","White","WhiteSmoke","Yellow","YellowGreen"];
 ["#ff0000", "#ff4000", "#ff8000", "#ffbf00", "#ffff00", "#bfff00", "#80ff00", "#40ff00", "#00ff00", "#00ff40", "#00ff80", "#00ffbf", "#00ffff", "#00bfff", "#0080ff", "#0040ff", "#0000ff", "#4000ff", "#8000ff", "#bf00ff", "#ff00ff", "#ff00bf", "#ff0080", "#ff0040", "#ff0000"];
const canvas = $("canvas");
canvas.locked = false
const colorChanger = $('input[type = color]');
colorChanger.change(function(e) {
 changeColor(colorChanger.val(), e)
})
const colorOptionsDiv = $("#colorOptions");
const select = $("sselect");
const slider = $("#revisionSlider");
let eraserSize = 10;
slider.change(function(ev) {
 console.log(slider.val());
 if (slider.val() > ctx.history.length - 1) {
  ctx.future.push(ctx.history.splice(slider.val(), ctx.history.length));
  ctx.redraw();
 }
});
select.val("brush");
const ctx = canvas[0].getContext("2d");
let selection;
$("body > div > button").click(function() {
 let height = $('#height').val();
 let width = $('#width').val();
 let go = true;
 if (height === "" & width === "") {
  go = confirm("You haven't entered any dimensions. Would you like to go with your screen dimensions?\nThey are:\nWidth: " + window.innerWidth + "\nHeight: " + window.innerHeight);
  width = screen.width //window.innerWidth //- 8 ///1.06;
  height = screen.height //window.innerHeight //- 5 ///1.2;
 }
 else if (height < 300 && width >= 300) {
  go = confirm("Are you sure you don't want your canvas higher?");
 }
 else if (width < 300 && height >= 300) {
  go = confirm("Are you sure you don't want your canvas wider?");
 }
 else if (width < 300 && height < 300) {
  go = confirm("Are you sure you don't want a larger canvas?");
 }
 if (go) {
  updateCanvasSize()

  new ResizeObserver(updateCanvasSize).observe(canvas.parent()[0])
  $(this.parentNode).remove();
  $('#mainDiv, #actions, #paintControls').show();
  document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen()
  canvas.parent().height(height)
  canvas.parent().width(width)
 }
 else return;
});
$("body > div > input").keyup(function(ev) {
 if (ev.keyCode === 13) {
  $("body > div > button").click();
 }
});

function pencilDown(ev) {
 if (ev.buttons - 0 == 1) {
  ctx.redraw();
  let mode = select.val().toLowerCase();
  canvas.pointerIsDown = true;
  if (mode === "brush") {
   canvas.changed = true;
   let drawing = function() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(ev.offsetX, ev.offsetY);
   };
   drawing.ev = ev;
   ctx.draw(drawing);
  }
  else if (mode === "line") {
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.moveTo(ev.offsetX, ev.offsetY);
  }
  else if (mode === 'select') {
   ctx.setLineDash([8, 16]);
   ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  }
  canvas.lastPointerDown = ev;
 }
}
canvas.on('pointerdown', pencilDown);
canvas.on('pointerdown', function() {
 $("#paintControls").css({ top: "-50px" });
 $("#actions").css({ width: 0 });
});
$(window).on('pointerup', function(ev) {
 canvas.pointerIsDown = false;
});

function pencilUp(ev) {
 let mode = select.val().toLowerCase();
 canvas.lastPointerUp = ev;
 if (mode == "line") {
  ctx.fillLine(ctx.lastPointerDown.offsetX, ctx.lastPointerDown.offsetY, ev.offsetX, ev.offsetY);
 }
 else if (mode === "select") {
  ctx.setLineDash([0, 0]);
  selection = [canvas.lastPointerDown.offsetX, canvas.lastPointerDown.offsetY, 0 - (canvas.lastPointerDown.offsetX - canvas.lastPointerUp.offsetX), 0 - (canvas.lastPointerDown.offsetY - ev.offsetY)];
  ctx.redraw();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#0099ff"
  ctx.strokeRect(...selection);
 }
}
canvas.on('pointerup', pencilUp);
canvas.on('pointerup', function() {
 $("#paintControls").css({ top: "2px" });
 $("#actions").css({ width: "40px" });
});

function pencilMove(ev) {
 if (canvas.pointerIsDown) {
  let endX = ev.offsetX - canvas.lastPointerDown.offsetX;
  let endY = ev.offsetY - canvas.lastPointerDown.offsetY;
  let mode = select.val().toLowerCase();
  if (mode === "brush") {
   let funcs = [
    { func: "lineTo", args: [ev.offsetX, ev.offsetY] },
    { func: "stroke", args: [] }
   ];
   let drawing = new Drawing([], ev);
   drawing.functions = funcs;
   ctx.draw(drawing);

   // implent this later, it looks very cool! ctx.closePath();
   // and this ctx.fill();
  }
  else if (mode === "line") {
   // try{
   //  tempLine.clear();
   // } catch (e){}
   // tempLine = ctx.temporaryLine(ctx.lastPointerDown.offsetX, ctx.lastPointerDown.offsetY, ev.offsetX, ev.offsetY, 3);
   ctx.redraw();
   ctx.lineTo(ev.offsetX, ev.offsetY);
   ctx.stroke();
  }
  else if (mode === "select") {
   ctx.redraw();
   ctx.setLineDash([6, 8]);
   ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
   // if (endX<0)endX=0;
   // let drawing = new Drawing([{func:"strokeRect", args: [canvas.lastPointerDown.offsetX, canvas.lastPointerDown.offsetY, endX, endY]}], ev);
   // ctx.draw(drawing, false);
   ctx.strokeRect(canvas.lastPointerDown.offsetX, canvas.lastPointerDown.offsetY, endX, endY);
  }
  else if (mode === "bug1") {
   // ctx.redraw();
   var drawing = new Drawing([{ func: "strokeRect", args: [canvas.lastPointerDown.offsetX, canvas.lastPointerDown.offsetY, endX, endY] }], ev);
   ctx.draw(drawing);
  }
  else if (mode === "bug2") {
   ctx.future.push(ctx.history.pop())
   ctx.redraw();
   var drawing = new Drawing([{ func: "strokeRect", args: [canvas.lastPointerDown.offsetX, canvas.lastPointerDown.offsetY, endX, endY] }], ev);
   ctx.draw(drawing);
  }
  else if (mode === "timeline") {
   ctx.future.push(ctx.history.pop())
   ctx.redraw();
  }
  else if (mode === "dots") {
   let drawing = new Drawing([{ func: "fillRect", args: [ev.offsetX, ev.offsetY, 1, 1] }], ev);
   ctx.draw(drawing);
  }
  else if (mode === "eraser") {
   let drawing = new Drawing([{ func: "clearRect", args: [ev.offsetX - eraserSize / 2, ev.offsetY - eraserSize / 2, eraserSize, eraserSize] }]);
   ctx.draw(drawing);
  }
  canvas.lastPointerMove = ev;
 }
}
canvas.on('pointermove', pencilMove);
$(window).on('keydown', function(ev) {
 if (ev.keyCode === 8 || ev.keyCode === 46) {
  var drawing = new Drawing([{ func: "clearRect", args: selection }], ev);
  ctx.draw(drawing);
  ctx.redraw();
 }
 else if (ev.key.toLowerCase() === 'z' && ev.ctrlKey && ev.shiftKey) {
  ctx.future.push(ctx.history.pop());
  ctx.redraw();
 }
 else if (ev.key.toLowerCase() === 'y' && ev.ctrlKey && ev.shiftKey) {
  ctx.history.push(ctx.future.pop());
  ctx.redraw();
 }
});

function undo() {
 for (var item of ctx.history.slice().reverse()) {
  try {
   if (item.ev.type === "pointerdown") {
    locationInArray = ctx.history.indexOf(item);
    ctx.future = ctx.future.concat(ctx.history.splice(locationInArray, ctx.history.length - locationInArray));
    ctx.redraw();
    return;
   }
  }
  catch (e) { continue; }
 }
}

function redo() {
 for (var item of ctx.future.slice().reverse()) {
  try {
   if (item.ev.type === "pointerdown") {
    locationInArray = ctx.future.indexOf(item);
    ctx.history = ctx.history.concat(ctx.future.splice(locationInArray, ctx.future.length - locationInArray));
    ctx.redraw();
    return;
   }
  }
  catch (e) { continue; }
 }
}
$(window).on('keyup', function(ev) {
 var locationInArray
 if (ev.key.toLowerCase() === 's' && ev.ctrlKey && ev.shiftKey) {
  save();
 }
 if (ev.key.toLowerCase() === 'z' && ev.ctrlKey && !ev.shiftKey) {
  undo()
 }
 if (ev.key.toLowerCase() === 'y' && ev.ctrlKey && !ev.shiftKey) {
  redo()
 }
});
colorChanger.change(function() {
 var drawing = new Drawing([{ func: "set", args: [{ 'strokeStyle': this.value, 'fillStyle': this.value, 'shadowColor': this.value }] }], ev);
 ctx.draw(drawing);
 addNewColor(this.value);
});
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.clear = function(record, ev) {
 ev = ev || {};
 if (record) {
  var drawing = new Drawing([{ func: "clearRect", args: [0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height] }], ev);
  this.draw(drawing);
 }
 else
  this.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
};
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.clearSelection = function(record = true, ev = null) {
 if (selection) {
  x = selection[0];
  y = selection[1];
  w = selection[2];
  h = selection[3]
  selection = null
 }
 else {
  if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to clear the canvas?")) return
  x = 0;
  y = 0;
  w = this.canvas.width;
  h = this.canvas.height;
 }
 if (record) {
  var drawing = new Drawing([{ func: "clearRect", args: [x, y, w, h] }], ev);
  this.draw(drawing);
 }
 else
  this.clearRect(x, y, w, h);
 ctx.redraw()
};
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.draw = function(drawing, record = true) {
 if (drawing instanceof Drawing) {
  for (func of drawing.functions) {
   this[func.func](...func.args);
  }
 }
 else if (drawing instanceof Function) {
  if (drawing.args)
   drawing(...drawing.args);
  else drawing();
 }
 else {
  drawing.toString = drawing.toString || function() { return this; };
  throw TypeError(`${drawing.toString()+"yt"} is not a Drawing or Function!`);
 }
 if (record) {
  this.add(drawing);
  slider.attr("max", Number(slider.attr("max")) + 1);

 }
 this.lastRender = URLToImageEl(canvas.toURL())
};
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.history = [];
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.future = [];
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.add = function(drawing) {
 this.history.push(drawing);
};

CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.redraw = function(cache = false) {
 var _ctx = this
 this.clear();
 if (!cache) {
  for (var drawing of this.history) {
   this.draw(drawing, false);
  }
 }
 else {
  this.draw(function() {
   console.log(_ctx.lastRender)
   _ctx.drawImage(_ctx.lastRender, 0, 0)

  })
 }
};
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.set = function(prop, val) {
 if (typeof prop === "string" & typeof val === "string" | typeof val === "number")
  this[prop] = val;
 else if (typeof prop === "object" & !val) {
  for (var key in prop) {
   this[key] = prop[key]
  }
 }
 else throw Error("Invalid arguments")
}
$("#strokeWidthChanger input").change(function() {
 ctx.lineWidth = this.value;
});
for (var color of CSS_COLORS) {
 addNewColor(color);
}

function addNewColor(color) {
 colorOptionsDiv.html(colorOptionsDiv.html() + `<button class="colorOption" style="background-color:${color}" onclick="changeColor('${color}')"></button>`);
}

function changeColor(color, ev) {
 ev = ev || {};
 if (color.startsWith("rgb"))
  colorChanger.val(rgbToHex(color));
 else colorChanger.val(color);
 var colorChange = function() {
  var drawing = new Drawing([{ func: "set", args: [{ 'strokeStyle': color, 'fillStyle': color, 'shadowColor': color }] }], ev);
  ctx.draw(drawing);
 };
 ctx.draw(colorChange);
}
canvas.toURL = function() {
 return this[0].toDataURL()
}

function save() {
 ctx.redraw();
 var dataUrl = canvas.toURL();
 var a = document.createElement("A");
 a.download = $("#downloadName").val();
 a.href = dataUrl;
 a.click();
}

function configCanvas() {
 ctx.draw(function() {
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.setLineDash([0, 0]);
  ctx.lineJoin = "round";
  ctx.lineCap = "round";
  ctx.shadowBlur = 1;
  ctx.shadowColor = ctx.strokeStyle
  ctx.lastRender = new Image()
  ctx.lastRender.src = ""
  this.type = null;
 });
}
configCanvas();
sselectsOptions = $("sselect soption");
sselectsOptions.click(function() {
 $(this).closest("sselect").val(this.getAttribute("value"));
})

function componentToHex(c) {
 var hex = c.toString(16);
 return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
}

function rgbToHex(color) {
 color = color.replace("rgb(", "").replace(")", "").replace(" ", "").split(",")
 console.log(color)
 r = color[0];
 g = color[1];
 b = color[2];
 return "#" + componentToHex(r) + componentToHex(g) + componentToHex(b);
}
let brushes = {
 pencil: function() {

 }
}

function updateCanvasSize() {
 canvas.attr('width', canvas.parent().width() - 6)
 canvas.attr('height', canvas.parent().height() - 6)
 ctx.redraw()
}

function URLToImageEl(URL) {
 var img = new Image()
 img.src = URL
 return img
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="startDiv">
  <h3>Enter a height and width to create your canvas with those dimensions</h3>
  <h5>You can resize it at any point after creation.</h5>
  <input placeholder="Height" id="height" type="number" />
  <br />
  <input placeholder="Width" id="width" type="number" />
  <button>Create canvas</button>
 </div>
 <div id="mainDiv" style="display: none;">
  <div id="canvas-container">
   <canvas></canvas>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="paintControls" style="display: none">
  <div id="colorOptions">
   <div id="colorPickerContainer">
    <input type="color" class="field-radio" />
   </div>
   <button class="colorOption" style="background-color:black" onclick="changeColor('black')"></button>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="actions" style="display: none">
  <div class="tooltip">
   <span class="tooltiptext">Clear canvas</span>
   <i onclick="ctx.clearSelection()" class="material-icons awesomeButton action">clear</i>
  </div>
  <div class="tooltip">
   <span class="tooltiptext">Download</span>
   <soption class="material-icons awesomeButton action" value="download" id="download" onclick="save();">file_download</soption>
  </div>
  <sselect id="options">
   <div class="tooltip">
    <span class="tooltiptext">Select brush</span>
    <soption class="material-icons awesomeButton action" value="brush" id="brush">
     brush
    </soption>
   </div>
   <div class="tooltip">
    <span class="tooltiptext">Select area</span>
    <soption class="material-icons awesomeButton action" value="select" id="select">crop_free</soption>
   </div>
   <soption id="line"></soption>
   <div class="tooltip">
    <span class="tooltiptext">Eraser</span>
    <soption id="eraser" class="awesomeButton" value="eraser">E</soption>
   </div>
   <div class="tooltip">
    <span class="tooltiptext">RectEffect</span>
    <soption class="awesomeButton material-icons" value="bug1">check_box_outline_blank</soption>
   </div>
   <div class="tooltip">
    <span class="tooltiptext">Tools and colors settings</span>
    <soption class="settings awesomeButton material-icons" onclick="$(document.body).append(`<div style='position: fixed;top: 0;left: 0;z-index:3;text-align:center;background: black;width:100%;height:100%'><input type='range' min='0' max='2'></div>`)">settings</soption>
   </div>
   <div class="tooltip">
    <span class="tooltiptext">Insert image</span>
    <i id="image" class="awesomeButton material-icons" value="insertImage" onclick="$(this).next().click()">image</i>
    <input id="imageFilePicker" style="display: none;" type="file">
   </div>
   <div class="tooltip">
    <span class="tooltiptext">Undo</span>
    <i class="awesomeButton material-icons" onclick="undo()">undo</i>
   </div>
   <div class="tooltip">
    <span class="tooltiptext">Redo</span>
    <i class="awesomeButton material-icons" onclick="redo()">redo</i>
   </div>
  </sselect>
 </div>
```

[Here's a pen with the CSS](https://codepen.io/mendymsuoi/pen/EpmgpM)

Comment: I'd try running a profiler (click the `performance` tab in Chrome dev tools and start a recording). This should give you an idea of what function(s) are using eating memory.

Comment: You probably had a message asking you to include code along with the link to your codepen. That is for a simple reason: we can't be sure that your link will always be alive, nor that codepen will always be there, so we require that all the needed information are included **inside** the question itself. And for a debugging question like yours, we even require that an [MCVE] be included inside the question. And pay attention to the Minimal and Reproducible part.

Comment: Does your canvas redraw prototype clear the entire canvas before redrawing everything? You call canvas redraw quite a lot and it may have an exponential effect on performance as you are rendering more and more lines with every stroke. I would suggest not clearing the canvas/redrawing unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Kalido, I'll hopefully make it into a code snippet next time I'm near a computer.

Comment: @Daniel Dees, I think maybe. But I haven't worked on this in over a month and a half, and I don't remember, exactly. I think when I debugged it yesterday, and went through each line manually, it was redrawing every drawing, but i couldn't figure out why.